# cordova camera capture using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'd like to capture an image using my phones camera, I have installed the plugin 'org.apache.cordova.camera' and all the permissions should come automatically, even though, I checked, and they did.

From what I understand, all I need is a button calling the javascript

```
<button id="photo" class="camera-control" onclick="capturePhoto()">Capture Photo</button>
```

and ofc, the script itself

```
function capturePhoto(){
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess,null{sourceType:1,quality:60}); }
```

I am doing this for android (using HTC one m8), am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: What happens when you call it? Do you get an error?

Comment: You should define both succes and erro callbacks, did you do that? because there might be a crash when calling getPicture without these callbacks. It seems in [js-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/Camera.js) omitted callbacks are not handled and therefore they should be passed.

Comment: I don't really know how to see if I get error, I'm using a text editor and a real phone, I will try to define succes and error callbacks and see what happends, thx

Comment: I tried the error callbacks and it works, don't really know why, but thx! If you write it as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when success/error callbacks are not defined and passed to *getPicture* method then cordova camera plugin works not as expected a reason could be that in the [js-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/Camera.js) it is not checked whether *successCallback* and *errorCallback* are passed and so **not** *undefined*. if there are no callbacks passed the plugin might not be able to start calling native camera on a certain platform(Android,IOS, WP8) because wherever success/error callback are used within native code the plugin is not able to call one or either of them.

An example of [Android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java):

On Android there is a method:

```
public void failPicture(String err) {
    this.callbackContext.error(err);
}
```

That is used to call passed error callback if for instance the currently taken picture(*bitmap*) could not be compressed using JPEG-Image compression processing.

Defining both success/error callbacks for every plugin should always be done because if there has been an error thrown within native environment/code your webview-app can be notified by this error and so presenting appropriate UI/Message to an user.

Hope this helps.